# vector string array input size issue

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int number;
    cin>>number;
    string s1;
    vector<string> lists;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        getline(cin,s1);
        lists.push_back(s1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
        cout<<lists[i]<<" ";    
}
```

When I enter 5 (for eg.) as input `number`, I am only able to enter 4 strings instead of 5. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the line `cin>>number;` there is still the newline character `\n` (because you pressed enter to input the value  )in the input buffer, to fix this you add a line with `cin.ignore();`

```
int main(){
    int number;
    cin>>number;
    cin.ignore();  // add this line
    string s1;
    vector<string> lists;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        getline(cin,s1);
        lists.push_back(s1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
        cout<<lists[i]<<" ";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing line-based input (`getline`) and non-line-based input (`cin>>number`). This causes your first `getline` call to read an **empty** string into `s1`, because the `\n` in the stream has not yet been consumed.

So `lists` actually *has* 5 elements at the end, it's just that your output makes it hard to notice.

In order to prevent the problem, convert everything to line-based input instead. Replace this:

> ```
> int number;
> cin>>number;
> ```

With this:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
auto const number = std::stoi(line);
```

This is a superior solution anyway, because it makes it easier to detect wrong input (when the user enters something other than an integer number for `number`).